# An error with "cordova build android"

Tags: android, cordova

When I try to use cmd line to build cordova project on the Android platforms,I always get the error:

Error occurred during initialization of VM 
Could not reserve enough space for 2097152KB object heap. 
And this problem can't be solved by add "org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m " in the  *gradle.properties.*

I used `'gradlew compile --stacktrace'`to get more information, I got the following result:

```
FAILURE:Build failed with an exception. 
*Where:
Script'E\cordva\helloworld\platforms\android\CordovaLib\cordova.gradle' line:117
*What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'。
>Unable to determine Android SDK directory.
```

the output in the picture.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xD1W2.png)

I used `'gradlew compile --info'`, I got the following result:

```
    An exception occurred while trying to find the Android build tools.
    Failed to notify ProjectEvaluationListener.afterEvaluate(), but primary configuration failure takes precedence.
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: buildToolsVersion is not specified.
        at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:173)
        at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.createAndroidTasks(BasePlugin.java:645)
        at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin$10.call(BasePlugin.java:608)
        at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin$10.call(BasePlugin.java:605)
        at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:156)
        at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:120)
        at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.lambda$createTasks$1(BasePlugin.java:603)
        at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$ActionInvocationHandler.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:93)
        at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$ActionInvocationHandler.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:82)
    ...

* Where:
Script 'E:\cordova\helloworld\platforms\android\CordovaLib\cordova.gradle' line: 117

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.
> Unable to determine Android SDK directory.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 5.186 secs
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0CyrI.png)

I thought the key problem is "Unable to determine Android SDK directory"
and I have configured the right SDK path, and eclipse can successfully run android application. Maybe you can help me with the problem or tell me some useful information. It has made me crazy.

Answer (score 0):

I'm on Windows (7) here and this is what I have in Advanced system settings :

**Path**

> %ANDROID_HOME%\tools;%ANDROID_HOME%\platform-tools;

**System Variables**

> ANDROID_HOME => C:\Program Files\Android

Comment: Thanks for your comment,but my Android Environment variable path is right,and I can eclipse can successfully run android application.

Comment: I realized I set the SDK path named ADT_HOME, it will have influence on the determine Android SDK directory?